# Scrolling video playback pageYOffset/400 Importance

Tags: javascript, scroll, html5-video, parallax

Can you please tell me the importance of dividing pageYOffset by 400 i keep seeing this in scroll based video control but can't understand why.

I can refer to this codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hfaLE and this question

```
// select video element
var vid = document.getElementById('v0');
//var vid = $('#v0')[0]; // jquery option

// pause video on load
vid.pause();

// pause video on document scroll (stops autoplay once scroll started)
window.onscroll = function(){
vid.pause();
};

// refresh video frames on interval for smoother playback
setInterval(function(){
vid.currentTime = window.pageYOffset/400;
}, 40);
```

[HTML5 video, pause while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756362/html5-video-pause-while-scrolling/28711008#28711008).